# the curvature as a function of $t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, curvature

let $r,c>$ some real numbers, and $X(t)=\langle r\cos t, r\sin t, ct \rangle$ is a curve.

Find the curvature as a function of $t$

I think that the curvature of a curve is

$$\left\lVert\frac{dT}{ds}\right\rVert=\frac{\left\lVert T'(t)\right\rVert}{\left\lVert X'(t)\right\rVert}\text{ Where }T=\frac{X'(t)}{\left\lVert X'(t) \right\rVert}$$

Since $$X'(t)=\langle -r\sin t, r\cos t, c\rangle $$ and  $$T(t)=\frac{1} {\sqrt{r^2+c^2}}\langle -r\sin t, r\cos t,c \rangle$$

It follows that $$T'(t)=\frac{1} {\sqrt{r^2+c^2}}\langle -r\cos t, -r\sin t, 0\rangle$$

Hence $$\left\lVert\frac{dT}{ds}\right\rVert=\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+c^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+c^2}}=\frac{r}{r^2+c^2}$$

But apparently, this is not a function of $t$, Does this mean that the curvature is constant?

Comment: I think you meant $ct$, not $cr$. Think about what the shape looks like and if it has any symmetry.

Comment: K=$\frac{1r^2 sin^2t+r^2 cos^2t+c^2}{1r^2 sin^2t+1r^2 cos^2t+0}=\frac{r^2(1)+c^2}{r^2(1)}=1+(\frac cr)^2$,$r\ne 0$. This seems to be the case that the curvature is not constant because each value of c and r usually give different values for curvature. This just means the curvature does not depend on t. Correct me and give me feedback.

Comment: yeah, I edited it @MarkS.

Comment: I was wrong about the formula for the curvature, see the edit@TymaGaidash

Comment: Trust yourself, @Yassir! You can start thinking of the case c=0, e.g. Then if you want you can calculate the curvature of the broader case $X=(r_x \cos t, r_y \sin t, c t)$.

Comment: 1. Yes, the curvature is constant. 2. A constant _is_ a function of $t$. 3. A geometric way to see the curvature is constant is to note that for each pair of points $p$ and $q$ on the helix, there is a Euclidean motion that maps the helix to itself and sends $p$ to $q$. The curvatures (and torsions for that matter) at $p$ and $q$ much therefore be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating and translating the curve would not change the curvature at a point. But rotating around the $z$ axis by $\theta$ and translating by $c\theta$ sends $X(t_0)=\langle r\cos t_0, r\sin t_0, ct_0 \rangle$ to $\left\langle r\cos (t_0+\theta), r\sin (t_0+\theta), ct_0+c\theta \right\rangle=X(t_0+\theta)$. So any point can be moved to any other point by this sort of [rigid motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation) exhibiting the [infinite helical symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_(geometry)#Helical_symmetry) of this [helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix). That means that the curvature should be the same at all points, and would not depend on the value of the parameter $t$.